# tvOS/SwiftUI: toolbar item steals focus

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I'm trying to add a brand logo to a SwiftUI tvOS interface. The main UI is a `TabView`. Focus works fine until I try to add a `ToolbarItem`. Once I do that it seems to steal focus and my `TabView` becomes unusable. Here's a simple example that demonstrates the problem:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                Text("Screen One")
                    .tabItem({ Text("One") })
                Text("Screen Two")
                    .tabItem({ Text("Two") })
                Text("Screen Three")
                    .tabItem({ Text("Three") })
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I keep focus from getting messed up? Should I not be using the `toolbar` to add the logo?

**UPDATE 1:** It looks like just adding `toolbar` causes a `UINavigationBar` to be drawn on top of the tab bar, which is why it isn't getting focus. Still not sure how to fix it though...

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** getting the image to appear but steal focus was due to the fact that I accidentally had two nested NavigationViews. After fixing that, I don't get any logo at all (unless I add it to each individual child of the TabView. See example here: https://github.com/taschmidt/NavBarLogo

Comment: You can try using `ZStack` to layer the `TabView` and `ToolbaItem` on top of each other.

Comment: I wasn't able to get anything working that way. `ToolbarItem` itself isn't a `View`. I tried doing `EmptyView().toolbar { ... }` but then nothing appears

Comment: I was able to it working by superimposing just the `Image` over the `TabView` in a `ZStack` (i.e. not using the toolbar stuff at all) but that seems a little hokey.

Comment: Big problem simply overlaying the logo, it won't scroll with content like the tab bar does :(